# Rails: How to save a cart to a user session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cart

In my application I have designed a cart while following a similar format to the layout in the book *Agile Web Development With Rails 4* and I have a slight problem. So a user can add items to a cart, view their cart, and see price of each item and also the total. The issue I ran into is when a user puts items in a  cart and then signs out, the cart keeps the items in the cart even when a different user signs in. I believe the proper way would be that each user would have their own individual cart.

Here is my user model and controller

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cart 
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        redirect_to @user
      end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :admin, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone_number, :address_one, :address_two, :city, :country, :state, :zip)
    end
end
```

My cart model and controller

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_part(part_id)
    current_part = line_items.find_by(part_id: part_id)
    if current_part
      current_part.quantity += 1
    else
      current_part = line_items.build(part_id: part_id)
    end
    current_part
  end

  def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price}
  end 
end

class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

  def show
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)
  end

  def update
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
      if @cart.update_attributes(cart_params)
        redirect_to @cart
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

  private
  def cart_params
    params.require(:cart).permit(:user_id)
    end

   def invalid_cart
     logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
     redirect_to root_path, notice: "Invalid cart"
   end
end
```

and my Line Items controller and current module (line items associates a part to a cart in my layout)

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def create
    part = Part.find(params[:part_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_part(part.id)

    respond_to do |format|
       if @line_item.save
         format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created,
          location: @line_item }
        else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
        status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end

module CurrentCart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private

      def set_cart
        @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        @cart = Cart.create
        session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
      end
    end
```

Any advice on how I can get one cart to be associate with one user would be a big help :) if anymore information is needed just ask. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha! I did this whole book and never realized this bug!

Yeah... so the session stuff is cute, but you can always make it more secure by doing something like this:

```
def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find_by(id: session[:cart_id], user: session[:user_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
```

Now I know you don't have the `session[:user_id]`, but I'm guessing you already have a pretty good idea on how to get it done. ;)

Hint: On Sign In

Comment: I am a little confused by what you mean by using Sign In to get the session[:user_id]. I have a sessions MVC do you mean I need to somehow incorporate that?

Comment: Well I tried creating an instance of cart in the sessions controller with these three lines of code 
  `@cart = Cart.create
        user.cart = @cart
        @user.save`
is this on the right track?